# Identify these window panels ~4x3

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

These window panels came in a bulk buy and don't fit any of the accompanying windows. I would have dismissed them as not LEGO, except the greenness exactly matches other trans green elements. They are approximately 4 studs wide and 3 high, therefore they do not fit inside a frame of that size, and are too small for the next size up.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These glass panels are

[Trans-Green Glass for Window 4 x 4 x 3 Roof](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4448&colorID=20&in=A)

from  [6940-1 - Alien Moon Stalker](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6940-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

they fit with

[4447 -  Window 4 x 4 x 3 Roof](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4447#T=C)

[4741 - Window 4 x 4 x 6 Outward Sloping](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4741#T=C)